# Replace string multiple times and save as separate files?

Tags: linux, string, search, replace

I have a file containing a list of ~100 nearly identical lines, each of which contains multiple instances of the string I need to replace. Let's say the string is simply "001". Each instance of the string within a single line has a slightly different pre/suffix that can be used for search purposes.

I need to create a new file where the 001 is replaced with 002, while everything else in the line remains unchanged. This will go on until, say, 300 - thus generating 300 different files, each of which needs to be saved separately.

So the first file contains a list like this:

`./program.exe -file1 001.txt -file2 blah1.txt -outputx x001blah1 -outputy y001blah1
./program.exe -file1 001.txt -file2 blah2.txt -outputx x001blah2 -outputy y001blah2
./program.exe -file1 001.txt -file2 blah3.txt -outputx x001blah3 -outputy y001blah3`

...saved as list001.txt. I need to replace the three instances of 001 with 002, and save that file as list002.txt - which would look like this:

`./program.exe -file1 002.txt -file2 blah1.txt -outputx x002blah1 -outputy y002blah1
./program.exe -file1 002.txt -file2 blah2.txt -outputx x002blah2 -outputy y002blah2
./program.exe -file1 002.txt -file2 blah3.txt -outputx x002blah3 -outputy y002blah3`

And so on and so forth until list300.txt.

If I were to do this manually, it would require searching and replacing over a thousand times. Is there a script I can use to find, replace, and create all 300 files, without having to modify each of them individually?

Comment: you will have to provide us the prefix and suffix strings, along with sample input and desired output

Comment: can you post it in your question .. its difficult to read in comments

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. Done. :)